Firebase Google Auth Youtube Redirect API Call
I'm new to using firebase authentication and I'm using google auth provider for logging into my application. I noticed that if I was signed into a google session (say gmail) in another tab and then sign into my application via google (using a firebase popup) that I would be logged in and routed accordingly. However, if I was logged out of google elsewhere, and then login using firebase/google popup, the login would succeed in the popup window but the URL at the top of the window would flash a redirect to: accounts.youtube.com/accounts/SetSID.
Sometimes there is a long string at the end of this URL that I can't see the whole thing.
Is this normal? Is it normal for there to be a long string at the end of the URL? If not, where could this redirect info be set in firebase, the firebase NPM module, or elsewhere so I can change it? Just concerned as I've seen online posts about hackers potentially abusing this URL in the past.

This is part of Google's multi-site authentication implementation and doesn't really have much to do with Firebase itself as you would see the same behaviour with any "Sign in with Google" button. To authenticate with a Google user session, the authorizing user must first be signed in to their Google account.
When a Google account is signed in, a number of calls are made to Google websites to synchronise the newly authenticated user session on those sites by setting the appropriate session cookies for those services so they are ready for use. This is the purpose of the "SetSID" endpoint, to "set the session ID" for that service.
The authentication steps for your application only start after the Google user is signed in. Using the information provided in your application's request for a Google user session, Google's OAuth service will step through the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant to return an access token and ID token to your application (normally via your site's built-in https://[APPNAME].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler endpoint).
If a user is already signed in, there is no need to call the SetSID endpoints as they have already been called in the past when that user initially signed in.
If you want additional details, Pragnesh Patadia has an excellent summary in their response to "How does Google achieve SSO between multiple domains?" on Quora.
